# jQuery mousedown event not firing for window in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-events

I'm having problems hooking up the `mousedown` event for the window using jQuery in IE8. I'm getting no errors, but the event does not seem to be firing. It does work in IE9 and all other browsers I have tried. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(e) {
            alert('test');
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).mousedown(test);
        });     
    </script>   
</head>
<body>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you just use .click() instead to escape inconsistent mousedown handling (especially in Opera and IE)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `document` instead of `window`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the global window.event object, and not jQuery's event object. window.event only works in some browsers, and it is not a W3C standard.

jQuery normalizes the event object so it's the same in all browsers. The event handler is passed that jQuery event object as a parameter. You should be using that.

```
 $(".class_name").mousedown(function (e) {

  switch (e.which) {
    case 1: //leftclick
        //...
        break;
    case 3: //rightclick
        //...
        break;
  }
});
```